# Only writing data to firebase if information doesn't exist - Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to only update the values email, firstname and lastname if they are blank.

I need this so that if the user decides to change these in the settings, they are not overwritten every time the user logs in with facebook.

Any solutions to check if the fields are blank without a datasnapshot? Trying to maximise efficency.

Current code when user signs in with facebook?
[image: FB Grab User Info Code]

Database Structure for each user:

[image: Database]

Comment: Please, add your code as text, not image

Comment: Not sure the question is very clear but once the user authenticates, you will have their uid. Once you have that read their users/uid_x node and if the data is not there, then update accordingly. i.e. Get the snapshot *before* attempting to write the data.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is using a [firebase transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#-runtransactionblockandcompletionblock).

A transaction allows you to check the current value of a DB reference before you set/update it. It's main use case is preventing multiple concurrent updates from multiple sources but it can be used for this case as well - read and then write.
In the transaction block you get the value of the DB ref you're transacting on & can check that the value is null (hence 'create' case) -> then update it as required and return `TransactionResult.success(withValue: newData)`.

If the object is already set you simply abort the transaction with `TransactionResult.abort()` and no write to the DB is executed.

Another option, that doesn't require a read/write, is to set a Firebase database  rule on the relevant ref that will only allow write if the previous value was null:

```
"refPath": {
      ".write": "data.val() == null && newDataval() != null"
    }
```

Writing a second time to the DB for an existing ref will fail. 
I'd go with the transaction - more expressive of the requirement in the client code.

Answer (score 0):

In firebase the only way you have to check if the current value of your fields in your database are empty is to fetch them before you are setting them.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the field is empty only by fetching them.Then Use this code to update a particular value

```
ref.child("yourKey").child("yourKey").updateChildValues(["email": yourValue])
```